# Blur page content on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I want to blur the rest of the page content once user scrolls upto a certain element. I am trying following CSS, but as I am having height as `100vh`, the page initially displays blank element with the height of viewport, and then scrolling further the blur works as expected

For below example, there is a blank space between para4 and para5, because of the height given to the blur div. But what I want is to para5 continue immediately after para4, and everything after para4 to be blurred out. The blurring part is working fine, the content is blurred as we scroll down. How to remove the empty space between para4 and para5?

```css
.blurTest {
  height: 100vh;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<div>
  header
  </div>
<p>para 1 <br> content</p>
<p>para 2 <br> content</p>
<p>para 3 <br> content</p>
<p>para 4 <br> content</p>
<div class='blurTest'></div>
<p>para 5 <br> content</p>
<p>para 6 <br> content</p>
<p>para 7 <br> content</p>
<p>para 8 <br> content</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time deciphering the behavior you're after. Please try revising for clarity.  Start by explaining what "a certain element is".  One with a certain class name? The _third_ one? One some distance down the page?

Comment: I have updated the question, and simplified the code

Answer (score 0):

I add a parent div for your blur elements with relative position.
you can use absolute instead of sticky blurWrapper class and then if you remove the blurWrapper element you can see all the elements without blur.

```css
.blurWrapper {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  z-index: 2000;
  position: absolute;
}

.blurContent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    header
  </div>


  <p>para 1 <br> content</p>
  <p>para 2 <br> content</p>
  <p>para 3 <br> content</p>
  <p>para 4 <br> content</p>
  <div class="blurContent">
    <div class='blurWrapper'></div>
    <p>para 5 <br> content</p>
    <p>para 6 <br> content</p>
    <p>para 7 <br> content</p>
    <p>para 8 <br> content</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```